# redircting purchased domain name to a server .?

Tags: web-server, website

I am probably not using the right search terms , so not finding anything on the internet .

I have a domain name  purchased .

However I do not know how to redirect the domain name to my server that i have created .

could someone help pleae

Comment: you need to set the nameservers (dns servers) used for the domain to be ones you either control or ones you can have influence on (such as with your hosting provider). - then setup dns records as needed that point to the IP of the server.

Answer (score 3):

Heres a link to an article on the type of [dns records](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_DNS_record_types) that you can set.

Mostly you'll want to be concerned with the A record and MX records initially.

Set the A record to your webserver, set the MX record to your Email server.

You handle all of this through whatever interface your Registrar, the company you registered the name with, has provided you.

Incedentially, if you let us know what service you used to register your name we can possibly give you some more specific guidance.